# sed select line and substitute string in one command

Tags: sed

I want to print **only** line 49 and substitute ',' for tab (ideally with sed).

```
sed -n '49p' file.txt | sed 's/,/\t/g'
```

How do I do it in one command without piping?

`sed -n '49p; s/,/\t/g'` would not work, neither `sed '49p; s/,/\t/g'`.

Thank you!

Comment: if the file is big, use `49 {s/,/\t/gp; q}` to quit early (syntax might vary depending on implementation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`49` is an address and `p` and `s//` are commands. You can prefix any command by an address. So, instead of using  just `p` on line `49` use `s///` first:

```
sed -n '49s/,/\t/gp' file
```

Note that in this case `p` is just a flag for `s///` and not the actual `p` command. For the more general case of arbitrary commands, you can repeat the address for each command `49s/,/\t/g; 49p` or group the command behind one address `49 { s/,/\t/g; p }`.

As pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67092411/sed-select-line-and-substitute-string-in-one-command/67092440?noredirect=1#comment118591805_67092411) you can speed up the command by exiting `sed` after line 49, so that the rest of the file isn't processed anymore (similar to `head -n 49 | sed`):

```
sed -n '49 { s/,/\t/gp; q }' file
```

Comment: Thank you @Socowi. That's exactly what I wanted. It's missing the 'g' with the 'p' to apply the substitution to all commas.

Answer (score 1):

You could delete any line that is not line 49, which ignores the rest of the sed commands except on line 49:

```sh
sed '49!d;s/,/\t/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with `awk`, you can use

```sh
awk 'NR==49{gsub(/,/,"\t");print;exit}' file
```

The `NR==49` will check if Line 49 is being processed, and if yes, `gsub(/,/,"\t")` will replace each comma with a tab char in the line, and `print` will show it and `exit` will stop awk from processing further lines.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '49!d;y/,/\t/;q' file
```

If it is not line 49, delete it.

If it is line 49, translate commas to tabs and quit.